# How to get image width , height, and file type using javascript On IE7, 8 , After select file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

How to get image width , height, and file type using javascript  On IE7, 8 , After select file ?

I try this but not work on Ie7 , 8.

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$("#myFile").change(function (e) {
    var file, img;
    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe you need to actually add the image to the dom for this to do anything.

Comment: @pquest: Without File API you cannot read its URL and data, so .. how?

Comment: Add the image to a dom element with display:none or positioned off screen, you can then get the data from it, then remove the temp image from the dom

Comment: I believe you will have to add the image underneath something instead of using display:none as I think dom elements return a dimension of 0x0 when they are set this way, but that is otherwise exactly what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

It will never work, because it is possible only with HTML5. See [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi).

Comment: Can i get image width, height on select file on ie7, 8 ?

With other trick ?

Comment: The only trick is to upload the image in the background through Ajax, process it in PHP and return ist size. But I am not even sure if you can do Ajax in IE7.

Comment: You mean , using ajax to upload image to temporary folder and then i will get dimension this image ?

Comment: Yes, it would be pretty much effort but it could work without File API.